# How to remove category URL indicator segment?

Tags: categories, url, segments

I have a products section with 5 different product categories and all products are assigned to one category only. The current URLs are like this -->http://site.com/products/category/oral-care/. I would like to remove the "category" segment so the URLs are more like this http://site.com/products/oral-care/.

As weird as this sounds I *have* done this before on a different site. I used a combo of GWCode Categories and LowSeg2Cat to create my product links based on nested categories and successfully created URL's with this format http://site2.com/products/food/fruits/. In that URL food is a category and fruits is a subcategory. I can't figure out what I did to get this working and can't get it working on the new site. Is there a different method? Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, this is a snap with [Low Seg2Cat](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat). Example:

```
{if segment_2}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="channel" category="{segment_category_ids}"}
    ....
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/if}
```

(If you're going to be using other filters, or pagination, in your `products/index` template, then you need to do more advanced checking in that conditional to determine whether you should add the `category=""` parameter - in which case I'd suggest using [Switchee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) for that conditional.)

When it comes to creating links to those category URLs, you can't use the `{path=""}` variables, but instead you need to build the links manually:

```
{categories backspace="2"}<a href="/products/{category_url_title}">{category_name}</a>, {/categories}
```

Comment: Thanks Derek! I was close, but your post got it working.